# PyQt-builder error "Unable to parse 'PyQt5-5.14.2' as a version number"

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
pyqt-bundle: Unable to parse 'PyQt5-5.14.2' as a version number
```

I'm getting this error while running this command.

```
~/Downloads/PyQt5-5.14.2$ pyqt-bundle --qt-dir ./Qt PyQt5-5.14.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
```

- pyqt-builder
- pyqt-sip
- sip

**System Info**

- OS : Ubuntu 20.04
- Pyhton Version: 3.8.2
- PyQt5-SIP Version:12.7.2
- PyQt5-bulder Version:1.3.2
- Qt Version(for --qt-dir): 5.14.1
- PyQt5 Source: [PyQt5-5.14.2.tar.gz](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/81/b9a66a28fb9a7bbeb60e266f06ebc4703e7e42b99e3609bf1b58ddd232b9/PyQt5-5.14.2.tar.gz)

**How I Prepared**

1. Installed sip and pyqt-builder using `sudo pip3 install pyqt-builder pyqt5-sip sip`
2. Downloaded [PyQt5-5.14.2.tar.gz](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/81/b9a66a28fb9a7bbeb60e266f06ebc4703e7e42b99e3609bf1b58ddd232b9/PyQt5-5.14.2.tar.gz)  and extracted it to Downloads
3. opened terminal within the directory and copied `gcc_64` from qt installation Directory and pasted it into PyQt5-5.14.2 directory Renamed it Qt.
4. Ran `pyqt-bundle --qt-dir ./Qt PyQt5-5.14.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64`

I also tried using 
 PyQt5-SIP Version:12.7.1,PyQt5-bulder Version:1.3.1

Comment: How have you installed Qt? Where did you download Qt from? Have you used the installer online, offline or have you manually compiled it to Qt?

Comment: i have used qt offline installer installed it to home path `~/Qt5.14.1`

Comment: Why use PyQt5 **5.14.2** if you are compiling using Qt **5.14.1**?

Comment: try using PyQt5 5.14.1 https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/fb/eb51731f2dc7c22d8e1a63ba88fb702727b324c6352183a32f27f73b8116/PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz

Comment: `pyqt-bundle --qt-dir ./Qt PyQt5-5.14.1-5.14.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64` it gave me error `Unable to parse 'PyQt5-5.14.1' as a version number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that pyqt-bundle assumes a default structure --qt-dir since it gets information from there. In my test I have installed Qt 5.14.1 in the "/home/user/61682732" folder with the following structure:

```
 Qt5.14.1
    ├── 5.14.1
    ├── components.xml
    ├── dist
    ├── Docs
    ├── Examples
    ├── InstallationLog.txt
    ├── installer.dat
    ├── installerResources
    ├── Licenses
    ├── MaintenanceTool
    ├── MaintenanceTool.dat
    ├── MaintenanceTool.ini
    ├── network.xml
    └── Tools
```

In the same folder download the PyQt5 5.14.1 wheel(download from [here](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/47/640737c9d2eb76a2bf6e8dc101dd195caea07985f1932976629c02ad1432/PyQt5-5.14.1-5.14.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl)) so in the end the structure is:

```
├── PyQt5-5.14.1-5.14.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
└── Qt5.14.1
```

Then opening the console execute the following:

```
$ cd /home/user/61682732
$ pyqt-bundle --qt-dir Qt5.14.1/5.14.1/gcc_64 PyQt5-5.14.1-5.14.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
```